# Regular expression in URL for Django slug

Tags: regex, django

I have 2 URL's with a slug field in the URL.

```
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.genre_view, name='genre_view'),
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>.+)/monthly/$', views.genre_month, name='genre_month'),
```

The first one opens fine but the second one gives a `DoesNotExist` error saying `Genres matching query does not exist`.

Here is how I'm accessing the 2nd URL in my HTML

```
<li><a href="{% url 'genre_month' slug=genre.slug %}">Monthly Top Songs</a></li>
```

I tried to print the slug in the view. It is passed as `genre_name/monthly` instead instead of `genre_name`.

I think the problem is with the regex in the URLs. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Django always uses **the first** pattern that matches. For urls similar to `genres/genre_name/monthly` your first pattern matches, so the second one is never used. The truth is the regex is not specific enough, allowing all characters - which doesn't seem to make sense.

You could reverse the order of those patterns, but what you should do is to make them more specific (compare: [urls.py example in generic class-based views docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)):

```
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.genre_view, name='genre_view'),
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/monthly/$', views.genre_month, name='genre_month'),
```

**Edit 2020:**

Those days (since Django 2.0), you can (and should) use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) instead of `url`. It provides built-in [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), including `slug`:

```
path('genres/<slug:slug>/', views.genre_view, name='genre_view'),
path('genres/<slug:slug>/monthly/', views.genre_month, name='genre_month'),
```

Comment: One thing to consider is using a sensible limit on the number of characters to match rather than `+` to avoid overflow attacks, e.g., `(?P<slug>[-\w]{1,255})`. You can even increase the minimum that way if you want to further constrain what you will and won't match.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that you can also drop the `_` from the pattern that [@Ludwik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262618/ludwik-trammer) has suggested and revise to this version (which is one character simpler :) ):

```py
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.genre_view, name='genre_view'),
url(r'^genres/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/monthly/$', views.genre_month, name='genre_month'),
```

Note that `\w` stands for "**word character**". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits. [more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

Comment: Thank you, you are right. My code was based directly on the example from Django documentation, which was latter corrected (between version 1.7 and 1.8), so it now also uses the simpler `-\w` version. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Glad I was able to contribute & simplify (even by 1 simple character). Thanks for your acknowledgement @ludwik :)

Answer (score 5):

In Django >= 2.0, slug is included in URL by doing it like below.

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('articles/<slug:some_title>/', myapp.views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    ...
]
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path