# works when I use post_id, but as soon as I change to slug it doesn't work...why?

Tags: python, django

I have a voting system I first coded without slug, but I decided to use slug for the post and the whole voting system does not work. I don't know why it doesn't work, it gives me 404error that indicates url is wrong but I'm pretty confident I set everything right. If you have any idea, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

views.py

```
def index(request):
 try:
        sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
        sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
        page = request.GET["page"].strip()
    except KeyError:
        sort_method = SortMethods.score
        page = 1

    if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
        thread_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
    else:
        thread_list = Post.objects.all()
        thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

    paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "posts": posts,
        "pages": paginator.page_range,
        "sort": sort_method.name
    }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)


def vote(request, post_id): #here I switch to slug
try:
        error_message = "Not a valid request"
        is_up = int(request.GET["is_up"].strip())
        if is_up == 1 or is_up == 0:
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                error_message = "please login"
            else:
                post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id) #I switch to slug=slug
                try:
                    vote = post.vote_set.get(user=request.user)
                except Vote.DoesNotExist:
                    post.vote_set.create(user=request.user, is_up=is_up)
                else:
                    if vote.is_up == is_up:
                        vote.delete()
                    else:
                        vote.is_up = is_up
                        vote.save()

                json_data = '{"count":"%s"}' % post.get_vote_count()
                return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    except KeyError:
        json_data = '{"error_message":"%s"}' % "Not a valid request"
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_data, content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    else:
        json_data = '{"error_message":"%s"}' % error_message
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_data, content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

urls.py

```
  url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'main.views.vote', name='vote'), #I switch to ?P<slug>\d+
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
# I switch to ?P<slug>
```

my index.html

```
<table class="table">
    {% if posts %}
        {% for post in posts %}
        <tr>
            <td class="vert-align"><div>
                            <a href="/post/{{ post.id }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"> #I switch to post.slug for every post.id 

                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                <br>
                <a href="/post/{{ post.id }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div></td>
            <td class="vert-align">
                <h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.id }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4><a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><span>{{ post.moderator.username }}</span></li>
                    <li><span class="time_presentation">{{ post.pub_date | date }}</span></li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Then I get 404 error. any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `\d+` in this line:

`url(r'^post/(?P<slug>\d+)/vote/$', 'main.views.vote', name='vote'),`

`\d+` means that it only takes numbers

The regex for a slug should be like this:
   `url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/vote/$', 'main.views.vote', name='vote'),`

as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322151/4724196

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been fixed.