# Error during template rendering

Tags: django, django-urls

i am trying to render the details page of the product by giving the url www.example.com/product_name/product_id. But i am getting this error.

Reverse for 'product_details' with arguments '(u'lehnga choli', 43)'    and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[a-zA-Z]*)/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

here is my urls.py

```
    url(r'^(?P<product_name>[a-zA-Z]*)/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'designer.views.product_details', name='product_details'),
```

and here is my urls in html template

```
{% url 'product_details' designs.name designs.id %}
```

and this is my views.py

```
def product_details(request, product_name, product_id):
    design = Design.objects.get(id=product_id)    

    return render_to_response("designer/product_detail.html", {
        "design":design,                      
        "current": "product_detail",
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: There's a space in the name (which can't be used in a URL) - based on what you're trying to do, it looks like you'll want a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

Comment: thanks but is there any alternative solution for this? how i can remove space in template tag

Comment: Adding an answer now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a space in the name (which can't be used in a URL). As I mentioned in my comment, you might want to look into a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

*However*, since you're looking up the `Design` by `id` in your view, it doesn't really matter whether the model has a slug. You can use the template tag [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) to just make it passable through the URL.

```
{% url 'product_details' designs.name|slugify designs.id %}
```

This does require a small tweak to your URL as well, because spaces are replaced with a `-` - and I just use [`\w`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322151/4974980) in general.

```
url(r'^(?P<product_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'designer.views.product_details', name='product_details'),
```