# Django SlugField are displayed partially

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck from a couple hours and I can't solve this problem.

The following code works well, but Url is only partially displayed when redirecting.

For example, When Slugfiled is blah-1, url is Displayed as /blah/(without -1).

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              width_field="width_field",
                              height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    hit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def is_past_due(self):
        from datetime import date
        if date.today() == self.timestamp.date():
            return True
        return False

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        unique_slug = slug
        counter = 1
        while Post.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
            counter += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

View:

```
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "succes.")
               #This redirecting is the problem
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/post_form.html", context)
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name="list"),
url(r'^create/$', views.post_create),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='update'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.post_delete),
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358685/regular-expression-in-url-for-django-slug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested this code but it should now work:

```
def get_unique_slug(self):
    slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
    unique_slug = '{}-1'.format(slug)
    counter = 1
    while Post.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
        counter += 1
    return unique_slug
```

The problem is when you are creating a new post the while block of your function is not executed because when a slug is already unique the while statement is false. This means unique slug is always going to be your original slug (without the number appended to the end).

A way to test this is to put a print statement inside the while block. Create a new unique slug and you will see the print statement is not executed.

In the code above we alter the code such that unique_slug is first assigned with the `-1` postfix.

**Sidenote**:
This code is a little inefficient (if you have 400 posts called blah your will be hammering your database 400 times). Would you not be better off using a url structure such as `<id>/<slug>`. By using id and slug as your identifier you would be guaranteed uniqueness for each post. You would be able to completely remove your `get_unique_slug` function.